# StatusCallback does not work as expected

Tags: twilio

Overview:

I am working on a VB.NET application that places a call into Twilio, the number is not a test number.  I am using the C# library with the code written in VB.Net.

When I use this line of code:
      Console.WriteLine(account.SendSmsMessage(Caller, to1, strBody))

I receive a text message on my phone however the post back is never posted to my website. I have included the URL of the site on the account under Messaging > Request URL. 
When I reply to the message, Twilio does make a post to my site.  From what I understand, a POST should have been made when Twilio was first sent a message from my application, however this is not the case.

When using this code, I do not get any text message and no POST is made.
     Console.WriteLine(account.SendMessage(Caller, to1, strBody, PostBackURL))

I have tried SendSMSMessage, I have tried it with the URL on my account and without it, 
nothing seems to effect the behavior.

I need the SmsMessageSid at the time the message is sent. From everything I have seen, Twilio does not provide a response other then what is sent to the PostBackURL, I could parse a response for the
SmsMessageSid however since there is no response that is not an option. If I am mistaken on that point that would be great, however it looks like the only way to get a reply is with the post back URL.  Thanks for your help with this!   Below you will find an excerpt of the code I am working with:

```
    PostBackURL = "http%3A%2F%2F173.111.111.110%3A8001/XMLResponse.aspx"

    ' Create Twilio REST account object using Twilio account ID and token
    account = New Twilio.TwilioRestClient(SID, Token)
    message = New Twilio.Message

    Try   
         'WORKS
        'Console.WriteLine(account.SendSmsMessage(Caller, to1, strBody))  
         'DOES NOT WORK
        Console.WriteLine(account.SendMessage(Caller, to1, strBody, PostBackURL))

    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: {0}", e.Message)
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue")
    Console.ReadKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar with C# and like you, I'm not getting the POST to the callback URL.  I don't know why that's not working, but if all you need is the sid when you send the message, you should be able to do this:

```
    message = SendSmsMessage(Caller, to1, strBody))
```

and message.Sid will give you what you need, assuming no exceptions.